# redirect signed request variable

Tags: php

I'am a Classic ASP programmer and need to check a signed request variable to redirect to specific URL in a Fan Page Tab depending on Page ID.

Aparently I can't do that with Classic ASP, ¿ some one have a code to do that in PHP ?, I know a litte bit of PHP.

Comment: When you say a signed request variable, is it safe for me to assume you mean signed/unsigned int? As far as I know PHP doesn't differentiate between the two, so simply checking the value of $_REQUEST["PageID"] should do the trick. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the http header with php, so you can tell the browser to redirect to a given location. [header()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is the function of your choise.

```
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

You want to redirect by given GET-Parameter?

```
<?php
   header('Location: ' . $_GET['url']);
?>
```

Then you can call it via URL: `domain.com/myphpscript.php?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com`

But be careful!! You should check the entered GET parameter before using it.